# Use a variable for JQuery element selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input field to enter a city name - the on click function for that fills in certain `div`'s. I want to local storage every input (maybe in an array) and every input value dynamically gets created into a button.  The buttons are the 'city' name inputs - on click of these buttons will repopulate the `div` data with that city name and its' info.  I am saving the city input as a variable and using that city name to be the `id` of each button. So how can I use a variable as my query selector?

HTML

```
<div class="city-search">Search For A City: 
            <input type="text" id="cityInput" style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            <button class="searchBtn" type="submit"><span class="oi oi-magnifying-glass"></span></button>

</div>

<!-- This shows the search history and is reclickable -->
<div class="city-history" id="city-history">

</div>

<div>
    <h2 id="city"></h2>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".searchBtn").on('click', function getWeather () {
    var cityName = $('#cityInput').val().toUpperCase();
    $("#city").text("The weather in " + cityName);

 // Create buttons for city inputs
    var cityHistory = function() {
        var cityH = document.createElement("button");
        cityH.textContent = cityName;
        cityH.setAttribute("id", cityName);
        var history = document.getElementById("city-history");
        history.appendChild(cityH);
     }
    cityHistory();
 // Update city name with name on button
 $(`#${cityName}`).on('click', function historyWeather () {
      $('#city').text("The weather in " + cityName);
});
```

Comment: It seems you already _do_ use a variable as query selector, so what is your question exactly? What is the expected vs. actual result?

Comment: It's not working. When I click on the button, it doesn't update the ```$("#city")```, nor does ```console.log(cityName)``` show the city name of the button.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like `$('#'+cityName).on(...);` as the query selector? That's what I usually do.

Comment: You're using an ID (`#city`) selector, but your element is `h2.city`.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to ```$('#' + cityName)``` and also tried using ```$(this).text();``` after the on click. Not working

Comment: @emsoff is right about the selector for the beginning of the jQuery. That does seem to be a little bit off.

Comment: What specifically isn't working? https://jsfiddle.net/w62f7k0n/3/. I don't know if you're actually missing the closing `})` in your code, but that will definitely break everything.

Comment: The code auto creates a button for every input value. When you click on the button, I want the ```h2``` to read ```"The weather in " + {button city name}```.  So instead of having to retype the desired city, if it's already been entered, then I can select that city name again just by clicking it's button. @emsoff

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing, though.

Answer (score 3):

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w62f7k0n/3/) achieves what you want. As mentioned in the comments, you're using an ID selector, when your target element only has a class. Changing `$('#city')` to `$('.city')` will work. Class selectors in jQuery are `.` and ID selectors are `#`. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: Actually, it can still be done using an ID selector. I updated that in the JSFiddle. The actual problem is inside the last click event function. But this answer is still true.